# Difference between transform.getRelativeMatrix3d().position.z and .z in Flash AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d

I understand why transform.getRelativeMatrix3d().position.x and transform.getRelativeMatrix3d().position.y differ (because that's the essence of Flash 3d space) but what does transform.getRelativeMatrix3d().position.z mean?  What is it different from the object's z?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi not to deter your attempts but it seems you want some more robust things for a 3D environment that it seems you don't really get out of the box with 3D in Flash.  Have you considered using libraries that wrap the low-level 3D flash operations such as Flare3D or Alternativa3D, is there a reason your choosing to go "from scratch" is this an academic excersize? http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/gaming_engines.html

Comment: Thanks.  You may certainly be right.  No, not an academic exercise.  It's something I've been given to do as part of a project — a series of small games, some of which involve 3D, which I haven't really worked with before.  But the 3D is just a small part of the overall project and the client doesn't want to invest in any learning-curve time beyond the minimum. Are any of these engines usable in short order (a matter of hours)? I really only need the bare minimum of flash 3D -- moving things back and forth and left and right but the Flash 3D API seems tougher than the rest of the AS3 API.

Comment: Sorry to say I don't have enough experience to give you any sort of perspective on what would be best (also don't really know what you're trying to accomplish well enough).  I was one link away from a better page here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/stage3d.html I was just looking at Flare3D and it looks pretty promising.  I'm working on the early stages of a 3D game myself but only modeling things and haven't come to the point of picking a framework yet (want to stay platform agnostic though).